# proxy_http time out error

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

Hello Can someone help me to resolve the below error

```
[Tue Dec 13 21:07:12.176702 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 9437372:tid 5398] (78)Connection timed out: [client 111.113.130.243:45615] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 192.168.10.20:80
[Tue Dec 13 21:07:12.176790 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 9437372:tid 5398] [client 111.113.130.243:45615] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /deto/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties
[Tue Dec 13 21:36:12.261230 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 10485878:tid 5655] (78)Connection timed out: [client 111.113.130.243:11084] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 192.168.10.20:80
[Tue Dec 13 21:36:12.261333 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 10485878:tid 5655] [client 111.113.130.243:11084] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /deto/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties
[Tue Dec 13 22:47:09.485419 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 9437372:tid 2828] (78)Connection timed out: [client 111.113.130.243:48852] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 192.168.10.20:80
[Tue Dec 13 22:47:09.485497 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 9437372:tid 2828] [client 111.113.130.243:48852] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /deto/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js
[Tue Dec 13 22:51:09.497259 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 6815772:tid 4370] (78)Connection timed out: [client 111.113.130.243:51259] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 192.168.10.20:80
[Tue Dec 13 22:51:09.497365 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 6815772:tid 4370] [client 111.113.130.243:51259] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /deto/javax.faces.resource/UKDGD56DadAKDJJADKkdj.js
[Tue Dec 13 22:52:09.500000 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 10485878:tid 5912] (78)Connection timed out: [client 111.113.130.243:52749] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 192.168.10.20:80
```

we are using Apache reverse proxy  and see the vs config

```
ProxyTimeout 1800
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass           /  http://192.168.10.20/ connectiontimeout=1800 timeout=1800
ProxyPassReverse    /  http://192.168.10.20/
```

Comment: logs from 192.168.10.20 please

Comment: its an application server and we don't have logs for the same

Comment: Can you try to replicate the proxy request from the command line on the proxy-server? By running `GET -USed http://192.168.10.20/deto/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties`

Comment: Either the server cannot access `192.168.10.20`, or the server takes too much time to reply to the request.

Comment: Server has access and all other urls are working, might be slow response , how we can handle this slow response issue

Comment: If your proxied server is taking longer than 30 minutes to serve requests you should probably be fixing it rather than increasing the timeout. However you can increase the timeout for specific URI paths by adding `ProxyPass` directives (before the `ProxyPass /` one) with a longer timeout.

Answer (score 1):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html

> **proxy-initial-not-pooled**
>   If this variable is set, no pooled connection will be reused if the client request is the initial request on the frontend connection. ***This avoids the "proxy: error reading status line from remote server"*** error message caused by the race condition that the backend server closed the pooled connection after the connection check by the proxy and before data sent by the proxy reached the backend. It has to be kept in mind that setting this variable *downgrades performance*, especially with HTTP/1.0 clients.